# How many 3 digit odd numbers greater than 600 can be formed using the digits(2,3,4,5,6 and 7)?

Tags: combinatorics

In my worksheet the answer is 20 but i keep getting a different answer

Comment: Can the digits be repeated?

Comment: @lulu's question is probably why you are getting the wrong answer. If the answer is 20 I would say you can only use the digits once.

Comment: The question doesnt specify whether the digits can be repeated or not so im assuming you can repeat

Comment: If you can repeat then you have $2\times 6 \times 3 = 36$ ways

Comment: Well, I expect that's the problem.  Work it without repeats.

Comment: Which means that you probably can't repeat. If you can't repeat then you have to look at which numbers start with $6$ and which start with $7$.

Comment: I guess its just the question not specifying whether or not to repeat Ive been getting 36 otherwise

Answer (score 7):

The first digit is either 6 or 7.

If it is 6 the the last digit is either 3, 5, 7.  The middle digit could be any of the remaining 4 not used.  That's 3*4 = 12 possibilities.

If the first digit is 7, the last digit is either 3, or 5.  The middle digit could be any of the remaining 4 not used.  That's 2*4 =8.

So there are 12 + 8 = 20 possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

Since the answer is $20$, you aren't allowed to repeat digits.

If you aren't allowed to repeat digits then first count how many numbers start with $6$ and how many start with $7$. There are numerous ways to do this. One way is to separate whether the middle digit is even or odd.

Number of numbers starting with 6 and having even middle digit is $3\times 3=9$ (i.e. $3$ choices of middle digit and $3$ choices of last digit since it must be odd). The number of numbers starting with 6 and having odd middle digit is $3\times 2=6$ (i.e. $3$ choices of middle digit and then only $2$ choices for the final digit since you used up one of the odds on the middle).

Similarly you get $3$ ways to make numbers starting with $7$ and having even middle digit and $2$ ways if they have odd middle digit.

This gives a total of $9+6+3+2=20$ numbers. If you are allowed to repeat digits then you just have $2\times 6 \times 3=36$ numbers (i.e. $2$ choices for first digit, $6$ choices for second, and $3$ choices for third).

Answer (score 0):

Hint #1: You can only use $3$, $5$, or $7$ for the unit's digit, since the number has to be odd.

Hint #2: You can only use $6$ or $7$ for the hundred's digit, since the number has to be greater than $600$.

Hint #3: Can you use the same digit more than once? e.g. Does $667$ qualify for your requirements?

Now use the [Product Rule of Counting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product), and the [Addition Rule of Counting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_sum), if necessary.

Can you take it from here?